# GitLab CI Attempts to upload artifacts before it finishes execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using CI/CD and I set a job that should take approximately `8 hours` to run. The time-out of the project is set to `1d` and the runner has not configured time-out. The results of the test should be generated at the end and uploaded.

The job seems to finish roughly at `4 hours` (half of the expected time) and attempts to upload the artifacts. However, as the script has not finished, the artifacts are not found and (besides this error) the job ends succesfully.

Does anyone has a probable reason for this?

This is the output with the error of the artifacts.

> Uploading artifacts for successful job 00:00 Uploading artifacts...
> WARNING: results/*: no matching files               ERROR: No files to
> upload                           Cleaning up file based variables

Comment: What's your runner type ? You should understand why your script didn't finished correctly. Are you sure no [timeout](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#timeout) are defined ? The "error" of uploading artifact is normal for me. This is always the last step of a job where `artifacts` keyword is defined.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. The runner is in a K8s and it doesnt has a `Maximum job timeout` set. The error indeed is normal when the files are not generated and they are tried to be fetched. However, the script does't throw any error not indicates that it has been terminated. Also, I add a consol print to show the end of the script but that is never reached in the job. Any idea?